# Java 'Skips' on .equals Statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, equals

My java program, with the section in question shown below, seems to be stuck on the if("".equals) line. The while loop keeps continuing, though NEITHER of the options in the if statement end up running. So, instead of printing out the new data (under the else) or printing out the information (under the default if), it simply keeps asking for new input.

```
        System.out.println("Type in government type. Enter '?' and click enter for list of gov types.");
        while(playerSelection==false);
        {
            input = fileinput.nextLine();
            if("?".equals(input))
            {
                System.out.println("despotic_monarchy, administrative_monarchy, constitutional_monarchy, despotic_monarchy, enlightened_despotism, feudal_monarchy, revolutionary_empire\n"+
                    "administrative_republic, beauracratic_despotism, constitutional_republic, republican_dictatorship, merchant_republic, noble_republic, revolutionary_republic\n"+
                    "papal_government\n"+
                    "steppe_horde, tribal_democracy, tribal_despotism, tribal_federation");
            }
            else
            {
                fileLines[lGov[nationSelected]] = "     " + input;
                System.out.println(fileLines[lGov[nationSelected]]);
                playerSelection=true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a semicolon immediately following your `while` statement, which Java will treat as the entire body of the `while` loop, resulting in an infinite loop.  Then it will never get to the block in braces below it.

Remove the semicolon, so your intended block in braces will actually be the `while` loop block.

Comment: Another idiosyncrasy of java that drives me mad. Why can't blank statements throw a compile error?

Comment: @Cruncher A good IDE will give you a warning that your `while` loop is empty.  IntelliJ highlights it, saying "'while' loop has empty body".  Even so, it is legal Java unfortunately, even if it's surprising.

Comment: @rgettman I use jGrasp. Also, now it seems to skip my nextLine() statement completely, then run the else lines and exit out of the while without getting any input from the user. Commenting out the playerSelection==true; has it run correctly, though it seems to run the while loop a single time before asking for input as it skips a line (which I can assume is the print in the else).

Comment: @Cruncher `Why can't blank statements throw a compile error? ` They have legitimate uses, such as in the method `String.indexOf()`: `while (++i <= max && source[i] != first);`.

Comment: Well, as for my second question, i'm not quite sure why it seems to immediately accept a blank string "" as the input, so I just added an elseif for "" that does nothing. Works fine with it added. Thanks again rgett.

EDIT: (Also, to whoever asked if I had a nextInt before it, yes I did. For some reason, your comment shows up in my inbox but not on the page.)